# I/O Activiy in a virtual disk after close the Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am seeing this behavior and I find it interesting.

After I close a Virtual Machine on VMWare-Workstation, even closing the VMWware-Workstation console I see lots of hard disk activiy on of the virtual machine.

I have seen this in the VMDK and in the VMEM files as you can see here.
[image]

¿Why could be this happening?

I dont think is the Antivirus software neither *superfecth* because I enable it only to fetch the boot files.

Comment: It'd PID 4 doing the accessing, so it's a SYSTEM process of some kind. Perhaps one of the VMware services is interacting with the file? As Mark suggested, Process Monitor could point to which is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

My trial copy of VMWare Workstation has expired so I can't check this out myself, but [Process Monitor by SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) is your friend.

Start it monitoring the system, and then do whatever it is that you did to generate this activity. Then use process monitor to filter its results to just that file, and have a look at exactly what DLLs or processes are doing what to that file.

As a side note, process monitor is also a great way of debugging stupid cryptic error messages, such as "The file was not found". What file? Well, process monitor can tell you because it will list the exact file that the software tried to access.

Comment: I tried with Process Explorer with not Sucess: this has lots of I/O activity but not CPU. So in Process Explorer  I cannot open the process *System* and sort its Threaths to see what is happening. I didn't find anything interesting, all the things that show me high CPU activiy are ntoskrnl.exe. I'll try with Process Monitor, if I Can, because the machine is almost completly frozeen when this happens :). Thank you @Mark

Comment: Process Explorer is *very* different to Process Monitor (which is the tool I suggested). Process Monitor *only* monitors disk activity, and gives you all the handles and instructions and it logs them all historically so you can scroll through and search to find those elusive handles.

Comment: I could find anything interesting with ProcMon.